# Stop my user controls initialization in Toolbox by using DesignTimeVisibleAttribute

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm using more than 300 user controls for building my enterprise application, every time I'm opening the application in visual studio and selecting one form it's taking 3-5 minutes to load the controls in the Toolbox, especially if the toolbox is showing it's taking more time.

Who I can use DesignTimeVisibleAttribute in my controls to stop loading them in toolbox?

Answer (score 1):

In general, when you start noticing that the Toolbox takes a long time to initialize, you'll want to take a look at the directory where the toolbox stores private copies of assemblies.  That directory has a knack for acquiring copies that don't get cleaned-up when they should.  Not exactly sure what causes that, a designer crash is a likely source of trouble.  It can build up over time, drastically slowing down the toolbox initialization.

The directory name is

```
   C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ProjectAssemblies
```

Where "yourname" is your user name and 11.0 should match the Visual Studio version number.  VS2008 = 9.0, VS2010 = 10.0, VS2012 = 11.0, VS2013 = 12.0

Have a look inside the directories you see there, they have unspeakable names, good odds that you'll run into stuff that should not be there anymore.  Just delete the junk directories.  Then right-click the toolbox and hit Reset, you'll have it back clean and fast.

Answer (score 0):

After checking I found that only I need to put the following before the class declaration:

```
<System.ComponentModel.DesignTimeVisible(False)> _
Public Class ControlClassName

End Class
```